# javafx bidirectional binding of read only property

Tags: java, javafx, bind

When I try to compile this application I get error about types not matching. This worker.valueProperty is read-only, so I think that this is the problem.  How to bind this property?

```
public void bindToWorker(final Worker<ObservableList<FileForTableView>> worker)
    {
        // Bind Labels to the properties of the worker
        rightTableView.itemsProperty().bindBidirectional(worker.valueProperty());

    }

CopyFileTask task = new CopyFileTask(source, destination);
            bindToWorker(task);
```

CopyFileTask class

```
public class CopyFileTask extends Task<ObservableList<FileForTableView>> {

    private File source;
    private File destination;

    //constructors here

    // The task implementation
    @Override
    protected ObservableList<FileForTableView> call()
    {
        final ObservableList<FileForTableView> results = Controller.getDirectoryContent(destination);
        // Update the title
        this.updateTitle("Prime Number Finder Task");

        try {
            copyFile(source, destination);
            System.out.println("file copied");
            results.add(new FileForTableView(destination.getName(), destination.length(), destination.isDirectory()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }
    private static void copyFile(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: don't understand the question: read the api doc ;) Hint: Readonly means exactly what it says ... and bidi binding implies writing ...

Comment: I know it implise writing, but maybe this read-only status can be changed or something?

Comment: Why do you want (or think you want) a bidirectional binding here? It simply doesn't make sense to change the value of the task.

Comment: @genek There is no way to make a readonly proberty writable. There could be a workaround but if that works for you or not depends on what you're actually trying to achieve...

Comment: when I try rightTableView.setItems in different part od code I get exception that it's bind, so it must be bidirectional to solve that

Comment: Why not just add a listener to the value?

Comment: The fact that your value is bound and should be set indicates a flaw in your logic. Even if you use a listener this could result in a scenario like this: The task is started. After some time the user decides to click a button to modify the property. A splitsecond later the task is done and overwrites the modification triggered by the user. You've basically created a race condition...

Comment: It's list of files and CopyFileTask just copy one of them, so it should update file list when it's done.

Comment: @fabian possibly, but not necessarily a logic flaw: as long as the manual setting is guaranteed to happen after the task is ready :). At OP: you have to unbind the itemsProperty after the task is ready .. you can do so by listening to the task's state property and unbind on a change to succeeded/cancelled/failed. Probably easier to listen to value changes, though, as suggested by others ..

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate property binded bidirectionally to your `rightTableView.itemsProperty`.

And change listener for `worker.valueProperty` where you apply worker result to that intermediate property.

Comment: In your new version the intermediate property does not serve any (meaningful) purpose. You could simply update the `items` property directly instead of introducing a new property.

Comment: @fabian Of course this only has a sence for case
when one wish to keep items after tableView was garbage collected (i.e. after a window was closed).

Comment: You should use `WeakChangeListener` instead, if you don't want to keep a strong reference to the property then. That's still simpler than creating a new property and introducing 1 binding and a listener writing to the property...

Comment: how to use this WeakChangeListener?